# Creating an object with an external form

Tags: python, ajax, forms

I have a upload form that is going to S3 --

```
<form action="https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="id_file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" name="upload">
</form>
```

When the form is submitted to S3, I also need to create an object in my db and get the id of the object. How would I do this (without redirecting to my view)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an iframe to send the form and js to search for the id you are looking for in the retrieved page.
You could also use another script to perform the post method like php with the curl library. You could grab all the data retrieved from there, search for what you are looking for and add what you need to your database.